# Proof that $3$ dimensional vector space can't be spanned by $2$ vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I was looking at the proof that the vector space $\wp_2 (\mathbb{R})$ can't be spanned by $2$ polynomials in the space.  In their proof they picked $2$ arbitrary polynomials and equated the linear combination of the $2$ with a polynomial in the space.  I've posted the proof below but can't see what they did at the end where they have the system of $3$ equations.  We have a system of $3$ equations in $2$ unknowns so we should be able to solve it.  Why is it unsolvable?  And also, is it true that $\forall$ vector spaces of dimension $k$ that they can't be solved by $k-1$ vectors?  I'm asking in the case of fnite dimensional vecctor spaces

Thanks

---

[image]

Comment: There are *more* equations than variables, so the system is over-determined. Solving the first two equations might yield a solution, which doesn't satisfy the third equation, for example.

Comment: I forgot about systems being over-determined.  Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author
found his mistake and so no need to keep the question.